# Optional parameters - specify one out of several

Tags: c#

I have a method which accepts three optional parameters.

```
public int DoStuff(int? count = null, bool? isValid = null, string name = "default")
{
    //Do Something
}
```

My question is, if I call this method and pass a single method argument:

```
var isValid = true;
DoStuff(isValid);
```

I get the the following error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'bool' to 'int?'

Is it possible to pass a single method argument, and specify which parameter I wish to specify?

Comment: In this case you need to call function as DoStuff(null, isValid);

Comment: @Guanxi: **nope** - not necessary - see the answers !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the first parameter is `count`, it is expecting an `int?` not a `bool`.

You can provide named parameters like it describes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

```
DoStuff(isValid: true);
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible.

```
DoStuff(isValid: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently when you call `DoStuff(isValid);` it's positional parameter. So it's trying to assign to `count` parameter which is of type int (nullable int) and throwing error.

What you are looking for is `named parameter` and in your case you should call it like

```
DoStuff(isValid:true)
```

So your method `DoStuff` parameter will have values

```
count = null 
isValid = true 
name = "default"
```